# How to get section heading counterpart of standard Large Title font

Tags: ios, fonts, dynamic-type-feature

How do you get the standard font used for section headings that is the visual counterpart to the default large title font (when [prefersLargeTitles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles) is on)?

By "standard", I'm referring to the font used for the section headings in the App Store, Music, Files, and Podcast apps. The section heading font is a smaller version of the large title font. Like the large title font, its size varies according to [Dynamic Type](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/#dynamic-type-sizes).

Comment: Are you asking about `UIFont preferredFont(forTextStyle:)` / `UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:`?

Comment: That may be part of the answer. There doesn't seem to be a built-in style for section headings. Maybe it's a matter of starting with the Large Title font and then creating a derived font from it.